I'm following along to a beginner course for Python on YouTube. I was told to type in "jupyter notebook" but I'm getting a error when I do so
I downloaded anaconda and followed the the letter the installation process (twice actually since I reinstalled it after this happened the 1st time). I have jupyter notebook installed unto my computer along with all of the other applications that came with anaconda.
This is the error I'm getting:
jupyter : The term 'jupyter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

jupyter notebook

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jupyter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException






like I said I do have jupyter notebook installed and when I run it I get this script at the beginning:
[W 2024-12-22 12:30:46.884 ServerApp] A _jupyter_server_extension_points function was not found in jupyter_lsp. Instead, a _jupyter_server_extension_paths function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[W 2024-12-22 12:30:47.545 ServerApp] A _jupyter_server_extension_points function was not found in notebook_shim. Instead, a _jupyter_server_extension_paths function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.

Another thing to keep in mind is that videos, while popular, aren't the best way to convey up-to-the-date information. Things change in open source software fairly regularly and videos cannot easily be changed to keep up. So sometimes be sure to step back and look at the goal of a step and not the actual way you are being told in a video. It sounds like you want to open Jupyter. The easiest way is from the Anaconda Navigator. If that works, then your install was successful. You share no details on that aspect. And why you cannot use that? As for the first comment, you also may want to ...

 read How do I ask a good question?, in particular the section 'Search, and research', if you have not yet. Overall that is very good guide to making a post.
